# Fluid animation, object which holds generated fluid

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm working with fluid animation and i struggle with one thing. I want my cup to hold the fluid that came from object which is set to Type: flow, Flow type: inflow. I've tried to set the cup to be effector and guide but that doesnt work i've also tried to set the cup to be domain, but fluid doesnt rly want to exists outside the domain to that doesnt work as well  :<. I read somewhere that effector has to have some thinckness to i add a solidy modifer, but that doesnt change anything.

Comment: Look if this may answer your question as well [I am trying to fill a bottle with liquid](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170112/i-am-trying-to-fill-a-bottle-with-liquid/170140#170140). I wrote the answer, so i believe i can say it should cover what you may need. In your case just think of the bottle as a cup, if you only have the bottom part of the bottle, it's pretty much a cup ;) And yes it needs a thickness.

Comment: Thank you <3 one question more tho, do you know how to fill a bottle/cup with exact amount of liquid, using inflow? ( ik i can use copy of geometry of a cup, but it wont look like its pouring from teapot)

Comment: I believe there you may need to use the "Replay" mode and adjust the length of the time the inflow is active and or the size of the teapod-spout (opening where the tea comes out from) aka the sphere of the inflow.